# Mapping ISO-3166-1 country codes to phone number prefix

Tags: internationalization, iso-3166

I am looking for the best way of translating country codes to phone number prefixes. For example, SE should map to +46, NO to +47, etc. Any open source java library out there that does the job ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at Google's [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). There's a ton of stuff in there surrounding international phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at it, didn't find anything, but I may have overlooked something. Will look again.

Comment: The country code info is obviously in there, so you may have to add in some functionality yourself (possibly feed back to the team too?). I realise it's not ideal :-(

Comment: Ah, getCountryCodeForRegion seems to do the trick, missing the +, though, but I can add that :-)